# DFURTSP Player ffmpeg audio not working iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtsp

I am using dfurtspplayer for video and audio streaming an ipcamera stream on my ios device. For reference: https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer.
It crashes with an error :
 malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff513290007: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I think it crashes at av_free_packet(packet) in AudioStreamer.m
I have everything to resolve it.The stream format i am using is rtsp.When i am playing a normal big bunny video from web its getting played fine but with actual camera stream it crashes.The codec it uses is "mulaw" in audiostreamer.m
Anybody has a good luck with rtsp video and audio streaming in iOS? Are there any other good libraries I can use?

Comment: Hi, could you resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem. :(

Comment: I have started using vlc now for rtsp streaming...it is very stable...